# How to get cluster details like clusterID from code running on hdinsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I need ClusterInner object using Azure API or some cluster information like cluster id etc.

But to get ClusterInner object or cluster ID I need to provide the authentication object to API, but **this code will be running on same HDInsight cluster** so ideally it worn't ask for credential or use some env etc (My spark job already running on this cluster and spark job need this information).

Is there any API or alternative there to get this information from same running HDInsight cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing my answer as per the comment

This particular method is not a clean way but you can get the details.
**Note**: This is applicable only for HDInsight clusters.
The deployment details can be extracted only from the head nodes. You have to  look for the field in `/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties`
`server.jdbc.database_name`.For example if it is `v40e8b2c1e26279460ca3e8c0cbc75af8f8AmbariDb` then you can trim out first 3 characters and last 8 characters of the String.The left out string will be your clusterid.
You can use Linux script within your job to extract the details from the file.
Below is the shell command

```
 #!/bin/bash
    string=$(sed -n 's/server.jdbc.database_name=//p' /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties)
    POS=3
    LEN=32
    clusterid=${string:$POS:$LEN}
```

You can embed the script in Python/Java.I am using Python to achieve this

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sh', '/path/to/script.sh'])
```

Comment: We are creating cluster on demand for every spark job, And don't wont allowing the user to provide cluster id (we are using internally for some information processing so user might provide anything), So we want to get cluster id using any API but without credential because job already running on same cluster. (In case of AWS we call API without providing credential because IAM role is set on cluster)

Comment: Updated the solution as per the comment

Comment: @Shramik If the solution fits your requirement, please mark it as an answer so that it can also helpful for others in case of on-demand cluster